# LSF different resource request for multiple slots

Tags: lsf

Is it possible to submit a job using LSF in which the initial execution slot has one value for rusage[mem=] and the others have different rusage values. Job is master-slave. Master needs lots of memory, slaves, not so much.
Tried various select specifications, e.g., select[ 1*rusage[mem=6000] + 2*rusage[mem=1000]]  but only get "invalid resource specification" errors.

Answer (score 0):

The general format of [compound resource requirements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bsub.__r.1.html) is: `<# of slots on headnode>*{<headnode resreq>}+<# of slots on compute nodes>*{<computenode resreq>}`.  Try this

```
bsub -R "1*{rusage[mem=6000]}+2*{rusage[mem=1000]}" ...
```